# How to decode diacritics in a string without allowing HTML using MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, diacritics, html-encode

Is there a framework supported way in MVC.net to decode diacritics in a textbox without just decoding the whole string and allowing HTML content?

If, the text box contains:

```
<b>Café<b>
```

When re-rendering the page it becomes:

```
<b>Caf&#233;</b>
```

What is the correct way to allow these diacritics to display properly? using the inbuilt decode option results in:

**Café**

I could make a whitelist and convert these characters on the fly, but that seems clunky as I might miss some or allow potentially dangerous characters through by mistake. What is the recommended way to support these characters in MVC5?

Comment: Are you seeing that in the HTML _source_ or the rendered HTML _output_?  Without checking a Unicode table directly, those two things are probably equivalent and display as the same thing.

Comment: It's in a TextBox input field. As you say, in display code it renders very much the same and so isn't an issue.